Issue with List in SwiftUI
I have the following view which consists of a list of pools:
var body: some View {

    ScrollView {

        ForEach(Array(self.poolStore.pools.enumerated()), id: \.element) { index, element in

            NavigationLink(destination: PoolMasterViewDetails(poolMasterViewRouter: EditDetails(), pool: element)) {
                            
                smallcardView(pool: element)
                                
            }

        }

    }
    .onAppear() {

        self.fetchPoolsInDashboard()

    }

}



struct smallcardView: View {

    let pool: Pool

    var body: some View {

        VStack() {
        
            HStack {

                if (pool.type == "Survivor") {
                    
                    Image("survival")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 120, height: 90)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                    
                } else {
                    
                    Image("pickem")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 120, height: 90)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                    
                }


                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
  
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Text(pool.name)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.textColor)
                        .font(.title3)
                        .frame(width: 225, alignment: .leading)
                        .padding(.bottom, 0.1)
                    
                    Text(pool.id)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.textColor)
                        .font(.system(size: 16))
                    
                    Spacer()

                }
                .padding(.leading)
                
                Spacer()

            }
        
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .frame(height: 120)

    }

}

Pool Store does sort the items as such:
let sortedArray = self.pools.sorted {
                            
    $0.id < $1.id
                            
}

IF the list contains multiple pools in the users dashboard, if the user click lets say the last item in the list, goes to the detailed view of the pool.
When they navigate back to the dashboard (list of pools) the item they selected is at the top of the list instead of it being at the bottom of the list (as expected). The list is also scrolled to the top of the list as well in the dashboard view!?
Since the list is also ordered by poolID which is why it was at the at the bottom of the list in the first place!?
I am unsure how to get this fixed.
I am expecting that the user clicks on an item in the list, navigates to the detailed view and when they navigate back that the list is in the same order (by poolID) and that the user is in the same scroll location or whereabouts from the item they clicked.
Can any provide any insight on this, do you know if this is a bug in SwiftUI?

The order in which the pools are listed is the order in which they are delivered by poolStore.pools. So make sure that this always returns the pools in the same order, or sort this collection before displaying it.

@BenzyNeez I do with the following : let sortedArray = self.pools.sorted {                                 $0.id < $1.id                             }

Unrelated but why .enumerated()? The index is not being used.

I am using that to place banner ads in the list as certain indexes.

Following up on the comments, the order in which the pools are listed is the order in which they are delivered by poolStore.pools. So you need to make sure that this always returns the pools in the same order, or you need to sort this collection before displaying it.
You said that the array is being sorted and assigned to sortedArray. However, this does not change the ordering of the original collection.

To sort the elements in place, use .sort instead of .sorted.
You could try changing the ForEach to use  poolStore.sortedArray instead of poolStore.pools.
Alternatively, you could implement a computed property for the sorted collection in poolStore:

var sortedPools: [Pool] {
    pools.sorted { $0.id < $1.id }
}

Then you can use this sorted collection for the ForEach:
ForEach(Array(poolStore.sortedPools.enumerated()), id: \.element) { index, element in
    // ...
}


The soln worked! Which i am extremely grateful for... BUT I just don't understand why it does and why my initial code had the issue!? Can someone explain to me why my code had a gap in the logic?!

Pleased to hear you've got it working, thanks for accepting the answer. It would seem that poolStore.pools is not sorted and the ordering can change after some kind of update. ForEach shows the items in the order in which they are supplied, it does not perform any sorting itself. So by pre-sorting the collection used in the ForEach, it ensures that the list always shows the pools in the same order.
